# What to use for paragraphs of text?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the standard MVC template in VS 2013 for a web site, so it comes with Twitter Bootstrap style sheets.

The web site has many pages of information text.  When I use the `P` or `ARTICLE` elements to hold paragraphs of text, these two have left margin of 0px, set somewhere in the style sheet, instead of inheriting from their containers.  As a result, paragraphs look ugly starting right on the left edge.

I can of course override `P` in the Site.css file, but is this the right way to do it?  There must be some reason why they have set a left margin of 0px in the first place, and would overriding this have any unintended side effects?

I also don't want to hardcode the left margin of P to some fixed value, but would like to just follow whatever its container has.

Comment: 0 is also the default value in browsers. Margins aren't "inherited" in the CSS sense. If it's 40px on parent, it's still 0 on children (so visually it's 40+0, not 40+40). I fail to see the problem: one usually wants text to start right on the left edge. Or did you add a border? Any code reproducing the problem or screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give some class to p and override the style. Left margin is set as 0 to keep it generic in nature. Overriding a class is of course a right way to style without changing the generic style. Giving a class name will help you to only override the p who have that class. Rest will not be affected.